# some UDF (in Excel) get calculated and some do not when Press F9

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

My Excel addin is written in C#, I have a UDF say MyUDF
In a workbook, I have so many cells that use MyUDF.
When I Press F9, I notice some MyUDF get calculated but not all. 
Why?

Answer (score 2):

When you press F9 Excel only recalculates formulas that depend on changed or volatile cells or are downstream in the calculation tree from changed or volatile cells.
So a likely explanation is that not all instances of your UDF are part of the recalculation chain.

Try using Ctrl/Alt/F9 instead of F9 : this triggers a full calculation rather than a recalculation

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl/Alt/F9 does calculate all. Still do not understand why Excel thinks some need calculation and others do not while they are the same UDFs and have similar parameters.

Comment: Just saw http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff475859(v=office.14).aspx, it looks like asychronous UDF is not supported in Excel 2007. I test with Excel 2007, maybe that explains the strange behavior? thanks